# Open a new JavaFX window on a second monitor

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to open a new window from a JavaFX application and set its coordinates to be be inside the application by doing the following:

```
secondStage.setX(application.getPrimaryStage().getX() + application.getPrimaryStage().getWidth()/3);
secondStage.setY(application.getPrimaryStage().getY() + application.getPrimaryStage().getHeight()/3);
```

It works fine when the primary stage is on first monitor. But when it is on second monitor, the new application opens right to the left border of the second monitor, but not inside the app.
It is as if the X coordinate gets rounded to 0 with respect to second monitor when it exceeds the primary screen's X bounds.

Please let me know how I can have same functionality/behavior on second monitor as on Primary one using same logic as described by my code.

Comment: I have the same experience.  I wonder if this issue has been corrected in the upcomming javafx 8, in which case it might be worth to wait

Comment: I will tell you more, I had same experience as you had with SplitPane. JavaFX is new, and we are in the middle of it as starts growing into something big. But I have a feeling we'll find an answer here.

Comment: I had the same problem when I set the X coordinate before showing the stage. If I call setX(x) after showing the stage, it works.